# Autogenerate Guid without Identity

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, guid

EF Core MVC, Code First.

I want to have a field on my table of Guests that is a Database Generated Guid.  I do not want it to be the PK, I am using an `int ID` as the PK.  The Guid is for other purposes.  Also, Ideally this field will generate regardless of a user being logged in to the app or not.

I try to use this on my model:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid GuestGuid { get; set; }
```

My data initializer does not create any guests, and when I try and Create a guest manually it throws an error saying the "GuestGuid" field cannot be null.

If I remove the DBGenerated portion like so:

```
public Guid GuestGuid { get; set; }
```

Then it just generates a guid of all zeros for every guest created.

I want to eventually import data from CSV or similar, and so I need this value to autogenerate by the SQL database, otherwise, I could use `guest.GuestGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();` on the Create method.

I think its something in my mapping, do I need to modify my GuestContextClass?

```
public class GuestContext : DbContext
{
    public GuestContext(DbContextOptions<GuestContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Guest> Guests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Guest>().ToTable("Guest");
    }
}
```

Please help, I'm sure I'm close but I am nowhere near an expert with .NET.

After more research I want to clarify, I want this field (maybe it should be a string>) to autogenerate a random Guid whenever a row is added, the same way the ID is generated for ASPUsers when using Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `public Guid GuestGuid { get; set; } = new Guid();` in your model class. so it will be initialized with the new guid instead of `null`.

Comment: This still generates a guild of all zeros.  How does the identity part of asp generate a random guild for the user id?  This is basically what I want to do.

Comment: Using your suggestion here generated all zero GUIDs for some reason. (ex: 000-00000-0000-0000), I made it a string and it worked.  I did not try changing your code here slightly to   public Guid GuestGuid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();  that might have worked, I made it a string and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

In your model define the id like this.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

This will generate automatically guid for you

**Update #1**

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public Guid ProductGuid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Update #2**

If you want to have a field which is not pk but it will auto increment it's value then you can define it like this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int NoPrimaryKeyAutoIncrementField { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ya, but i dont want it to be the pk for the table, i still want an int id as the pk, will this work?  Ill try it today and let you know

Comment: If you want to have an int id as your pk then this will not work. I have added an Update of how to make it work. I tested it and it works without problems.

Comment: Is there a way I could use the GID as the key but stgill set an ID to auto-increment with each added record?

Comment: Check the Update #2

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing, thanks for your suggestions and assistance guys.

I put this in my model (I changed the Guid to a string):

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public string ProductGuid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

The above works for autogenerating a unique, non-key guid, however it does not work when I import a list from CSV or excel directly on my SQL server, and so I wrote a simple program to fill in empty GuIDs from the controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddGuis()
        {
            var prods = _context.Products.Where(g => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(g.ProductGuid)).AsNoTracking();
            foreach(Product g in prods)
            {
                g.ProductGuid= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _context.Update(g);
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```